# Putting a minus sign infront of function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

What does putting a minus sign in front of a function do?

For example:

```
return order === 'desc'
? (a, b) => descendingComparator(a, b, orderBy)
: (a, b) => -descendingComparator(a, b, orderBy);
```

Comment: It flips the positive/negative of the value.  `var x = 1; -x; x = -1; -x;` <= put that in your console.

Comment: This is one of those things where you can just try it and see. Make a function that returns a number. Run it and log the result. Put a minus sign in front of it. Run it and log the result.

Comment: This is used to reverse the order of the sorting based on `order` value

Comment: Another way to do this would be to leave off the `-` and simply swap the order that `a, b` are passed into the second method.

Comment: if `descendingComparator()` returns a number, I'd imagine the minus sign multiplies that number by -1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It negates the value that `descendingComparator(a, b, orderBy)` returns, just like the `-` in `-x` negates the value that `x` contains. In context, what it's doing is reversing the order of the sort (presumably this is within an array `sort` callback or similar).

Comment: Basic questions are not necessarily *bad* questions. There's nothing wrong with answering them. In this case (as with many other quite basic questions), I decided to use a CW to answer it to avoid any appearance of having other motives than helping the OP.